# Почему в Си порядок вычисления подвыражений не определен?

Tags: c, операторы

В силу существования приоритета выполнения операций и правил ассоциативности, следует, что алгоритм вычисления любого выражения в Си является детерминированным.

На лекциях обнаружил, данный слайд:
[image: лекционный пример]

Что он значит? Что здесь имелось ввиду?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите, у вас в каждом выражении есть различные подвыражения. Компилятор имеет право сгенерировать код, который будет вычислять их в любом порядке.

Например, если у вас есть выражение

```
f(x) + g(x)
```

и функции `f` и `g` выводят внутри себя что-то на консоль, то порядок, в котором будет произведён вывод, не определён.

Для чего это нужно? Например, для оптимизации: если в вашем выражении есть одинаковые подвыражения, то удобно вычислить их одновременно, а не вычислять по порядку:

```
f(x * y) + 3 * z / f(3 * x * y)
```

может посчитаться, например, так:

- вычисляем `x * y` и кладём его в регистр `R1`
- вызываем `f` с параметром `R1`, результат кладём в `R2`
- вычисляем `3 * R1`, результат кладём в `R1`, т. к. старое значение нам уже не нужно
- вызываем `f` с параметром `R1`, результат кладём в `R3`
- вычисляем `3 * z`, результат кладём в `R1`, так как ни выражение `x * y`, и выражение `3 * x * y` нам больше не нужно
- вычисляем `R1 / R3`, результат кладём в `R1`
- прибавляем `R2` к `R1`, это результат нашего вычисления.

Если бы нам нужно было сохранять порядок вычислений, мы не могли бы запоминать общие подвыражения, и код получился бы менее эффективным.

Comment: Проблема не только в коде и его эффективности, но и в регистровом голоде компилятора. Именно поэтому код может оказаться совсем ужасным в оттранслированном виде.

Comment: @0andriy: Да, я имел это в виду, но не хотел слишком углубляться в технические детали. Я, например, не упомянул spilling регистров вокруг вызова функции.

Answer (score 4):

> В силу существования приоритета выполнения операций и правил ассоциативности, следует, что алгоритм вычисления любого выражения в Си является детерминированным.

Это не верно. "Приоритет и ассоциативность" задают лишь абстрактную синтаксическую и семантическую группировку между операторами и операндами. Но порядок вычисления такая группировка на самом деле не определяет. Это в школе учат, что выражения "надо" вычислять в порядке приоритета и ассоциативности. А в языке С этого совсем не требуется. Можно сказать, что "школьные" правила вычисления задают некий "канонический" порядок вычисления, но компилятор не обязан ему следовать пока он гарантирует, что результат выражения совпадает с каноническим.

В вашем примере язык С не гарантирует вам, что `x * y` будет вычислено до `d - a`. Это, понятное дело, довольно "невинная" неопределенность. Но язык также не гарантирует, что сначала будет вычислено `c * b` а потому уже результат умножен на `d - a`. Возможно компилятор решит сначала умножить `b` на `d - a`. Более того, компилятор может решить вычислять `c * b * (d - a)` как `c * b * d - c * b * a` если ему так захочется.

Отдельно можно заметить, что актуальность темы порядка вычисления еще обусловлена тем, что выражения в С обладают не только результатами, но, возможно, еще и *побочными эффектами*. В этом их существенное отличие от "чистых" выражений, принятых в математике.

Answer (score 2):

Что, например, `x*y` может быть вычислено как до `c*b*(d-a)`, так и позже...